# package injection in symfony4

Tags: php, symfony4

the problem is i installed a package via composer named carbon and i use it as dependency injection in constructor of my controller and when i run my project it shows me:

```
Invalid service "Carbon\Carbon": method "__construct()" has no argument named "$carbon". Check your service definition.
```

this is my controller:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    private $carbon;

    public function __construct(Carbon $carbon)
    {
        $this->carbon = $carbon;
    }

}
```

and this is my services.yml that i define carbon class and then use it in as arguments :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false        # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    Carbon\Carbon:
        $carbon: 'Carbon/Carbon'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        arguments: ['@Carbon\Carbon']
```

what is the best way to resolve this problem !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your services.yml

```
$carbon: 'Carbon/Carbon'
```